# Expandable List View Groups are not clickable?

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

Hello I have a custom adapter for my Expandalbe List View, but I cant make the items in it clickable?
Here are some snippets:
`createAdapter()` is called in `onCreate()`

```
    private void createAdapter(){
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_exp);
    final myAdapter listAdapter = new myAdapter(realm, this);
    expListView.setClickable(true);
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener((ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) -> {
        final boolean groupExpanded = expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i);
        if(groupExpanded)   {   expandableListView.collapseGroup(i);    }
        else    {   expandableListView.expandGroup(i);  }
        return false;
    });        
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Also I tried putting some code in the customAdapter's `onCreateGroupView()` methood:(check the SEE HERE COMMENT)

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {        //Group
    final Task myTask = getGroup(i);
    final String parentCode = myTask.getCode();
    final String text = myTask.getTaskText();
    final ExpandableListView myExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) viewGroup;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item, viewGroup, false);
    }
       //SEE HERE
    if (!view.isClickable()) {  view.setClickable(true);} //SEE HERE!<<
    final TextView myTextview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_text_view);
    myTextview.setText(text);
    final ImageButton myAddSubtaskBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add_subtask);
    myAddSubtaskBtn.setOnClickListener((viewL) -> ((MainActivity) context).createSubTask(parentCode));
    if (!view.isLongClickable()){    view.setLongClickable(true);     }
    view.setOnLongClickListener((viewL2) -> {
                final CharSequence[] optionsDialog = {"Edit", "Delete"};
                ((MainActivity) context).myDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(optionsDialog, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if(i==0){
                            final Intent myIntent = new Intent (context, InputActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("request", 6);
                            myIntent.putExtra("oldTask", myTask.getTaskText());
                            myIntent.putExtra("taskCode", myTask.getCode());
                            ((MainActivity) context).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 6);
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                        if(i==1){
                            realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> myTask.deleteTask());
                            realm.refresh();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                ((MainActivity) context).myDialog.show();
                return false;
            }
    );
    return view;
}
```

still, when I run it in the Emulator, the items are not clickable. (only long clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happening because you didn't override `onClick()` method for your `myAddSubtaskButton` as you did for your `view`

Comment: It's Single Abstract Method (a.k.a Lambda expression). You can see the "->" sign, so the 'onClick()'  is overriden automatically. Anyway I fixed the problem. It turns out I cant use both 'expListView.setOnclickListener()' and 'view.setOnLongClickListener()', maybe because one is called in MainActivity and the other is in the Adapter Activity. So i just removed everything I did with the 'expListView' and moved all 'onClickListener' methods in the 'getGrouView'. Works like charm now.